# Can someone help me with watson dialog

Tags: watson-conversation, watson

At Conversation starts box when creatin a dialog, I use a condition trigger and a response for watson to display. I also edit the anything else box reply in case watson dont understand the user intent. When testing the dialog. The dialog display the anything else watson response, instead of the start a conversation response given at the conversation star box intent. Is this more clear?[screen capture of dialog box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNtcc.jpg)

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read through the [help] pages, especially [ask]. You've provided zero useful information, not shown what you're doing, and given us no details. Do you expect us to see what you're doing by reading your mind, or are you waiting for one of us to teleport themselves to your desk? We certainly can't see your screen from where we are sitting.

Comment: Yes well lets see if a watson conversation user understand what I mean. At Conversation starts box when creatin a dialog, I use a condition trigger and a response  for watson to display. I also edit the anything else box reply in case watson dont understand the user intent.  When testing the dialog. The dialog display the anything else watson  response, instead of the start a conversation response given at the conversation star box intent. Is this more clear?

Comment: Thanks Ken for helping to be more specific in order to find the right answear.

Comment: You've not been more  specific. Your question has not changed. Information added in comments does not exist. If you want to add details to make it more specific, [edit] your post and put the details there where they can be seen. Those details help a lot to improve the question, but only if they're in the question. :-) It would improve it a whole lot more if you added the actual code you're using rather than just describing it.

Comment: What are you using for the condition trigger in your first dialog?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the first dialog to be processed the very first time a new user starts a conversation (i.e. a new context is created) then you can set the trigger to "conversation_start". See the following image:

[image: Conversation start]